# Adding Wordpress Categories Based On Post Content

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site that users can login to and make posts. I want to add some functionality to their posts. Basically, I want to provide the ability for the user to use reserved characters to assign a category to the post.

So, if a user posts "I am learning about #programming", that post would be assigned to the programming category.

What is the best way to do this in the Wordpress universe?

Currently I am envisioning a plugin that runs at the time the post is made to parse the user's input and then assign the category. If so, how do I get my plugin to run at the time the post is made? Is there an API to assign categories to a post, or should I do that through manual database insertions?

Comment: You should look at the auto tagging plugins, they typically don't run automatically but after you've entered post content you can click a button and they'll suggest tags which you can accept or remove. I'm sure it wouldn't be hard to modify them to create category suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Take a look at [WordPress Hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks_2.0.x). You're interested in the *edit_post* hook.

Within a custom callback you can parse the content and look for your category hashes. Then use native WordPress functions to query an existing category or create a new one. Most of the complex logic will be in the latter part. The rest should be string manipulation.

This doesn't necessarily have to be a plugin. This could live in your functions.php file of your theme.

Remember, the codex is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Two questions: 1) would the right hook really be edit_post (and not publish_post or save_post)? 2) Is there anything you can point me to that would help with finding the Wordpress functions for querying existing categories and creating new ones?

Comment: You'll have to do research to determine which of those three work best for you. Maybe *publish_post*. As far as category methods: take a look at [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) and [`wp_create_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_category) to get you started.