# Wordpress Category Functions

Tags: wordpress

This is a followup to my question about [programmatically adding wordpress categories based on post content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748893/adding-wordpress-categories-based-on-post-content).

What function(s) are available in the Wordpress universe to enable a plugin developer to:

1. Check for the existence of a category
2. Create a new category
3. Assign a post to a category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about these:

1. To see if a category exists on a given post, use [get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)($id) and check what it returns. To see if a category exists at all, use [is_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)( $category )
2. use [wp_create_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_category)( $name, $parent )
3. use [wp_set_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append )

Comment: 2 & 3 seem right on there. 1 does not fit though -- I'm not trying to see if the category exists for this question, but rather to see if there is a category of the same name as the one I'm looking to assign (so that I know I need to create it).

Comment: Found the `is_category()` function from your links, so I added that in. Thanks!