# Wordpress Hooks For Responding to Post Content

Tags: hook, wordpress

This is a followup to my question about [programmatically adding wordpress categories based on post content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748893/adding-wordpress-categories-based-on-post-content).

Which hook (or hooks) are most appropriate for use in a function or plugin that requires access to the content of a post seeks to run code at the time that post is committed to the database?

The former question led to the suggestion of using the **edit_post** hook. However my reading makes me wonder if I should use **publish_post** or **save_post** instead, or, indeed, if there is an even better option out there that I am not considering.

What, exactly, is the difference between these three hooks? If I want something to run at the time a post is made AND at the time any edits are made, is there one of these that encompasses both events, or do I need to tie in to multiple hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `save_post` is the most reliable single method that you're looking for. More details here: [Details](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/save_post)
- `publish_post` does not fire if you save a post as a draft or schedule it to be published later. [Details](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/publish_post)
- `edit_post` is not fired in the case where a new post is created. However, `edit_post` is fired at many other times like when a new comment is created/edited etc. [Details](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/edit_post)